# Where is the "viewModel()" method in Androids Compose State documentation coming from?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

[Androids compose / state documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state) contains a sample referring to a mysterious `viewModel()` function or method, but as the documentation has left out all import statements I can't for the life of me figure out where this function is coming from..

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel):

> you can access a `ViewModel` from any composable by calling the `viewModel()` function.

> To use the `viewModel()` functions,add the [`androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$latestVersion`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle) dependency to your `build.gradle` file.

Finally use:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
```

Comment: Thanks! Wish the Android docs didn't leave out the import statements. That would have made it a lot easier to figure out.

Comment: Looks like it is removed in later versions. At the time of writing this comment, Latest version is 2.4.0-alpha03 and viewModel method is not there :(

Comment: @JunedKhatri The latest version for compose is lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha07

Answer (score 7):

Obviously figured it out 2 minutes after giving up and posting the question.

You need this dependency:

```
androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha05
```