# Save states between screens with BottomNavBar - Jetpac Compose

Tags: android, navigation, viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

As the title suggests - I want to save the states of screen elements. That is, I want to switch something on screen A, go to screen B, return to screen A and have all the changes in screen A saved. I am new to android development. As I understand it, one of the solutions to this situation is to use viewmodel. Check out the code below. I am trying to rewrite this piece with VM.

```
@Composable
fun DaysOfWeek(
    days: Int = 6,
    //viewModel: MyViewModel = MyViewModel()
){

    val states = remember{
        SnapshotStateList<Boolean>().also {
            for(day in 0..days){
                it.add(false)
            }
        }
    }
    
    val person = mutableListOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    val person1 = remember{ mutableStateOf(person) }
    /*val st = remember {
        viewModel.snap
    }*/

    Column() {
        Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly){
            for(day in 0..days){
                DaysOfWeekContainer(
                    color = if (states[day]) Color.Green else Color.Transparent
                ){
                    DaysOfWeekButton(
                        onClick =
                        {
                            //viewModel.snapChanged(day)
                            states[day] = !states[day]
                            if(states[day]) person1.value.set(day, 1)
                            else person1.value.set(day, 0)
                        },
                        day = day
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Text("${person1.value}")
    }
}
```

VM:

```
class MyViewModel {
    //state
    var clicked by mutableStateOf(false)
    var color1 by mutableStateOf(Color.Transparent)
    var color2 by mutableStateOf(Color.Green)

    var rememem by mutableStateOf(
        SnapshotStateList<Boolean>().also {
            for(day in 0..6){
                it.add(false)
            }
        }
    )

    //events
    fun clickedChange(){clicked = !clicked}

    fun snapChanged(int: Int){
        rememem[int] = !rememem[int]
    }

}
```

i try this and this is work! but does not save the state when I switch between screens

```
@Composable
fun DaysOfWeek(
    days: Int = 6,
    viewModel: MyViewModel = MyViewModel()
){
    
    val person = mutableListOf(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    val person1 = remember{ mutableStateOf(person) }

    Column() {
        Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly){
            for(day in 0..days){
                DaysOfWeekContainer(
                    color = if(viewModel.rememem[day]) viewModel.color2 else viewModel.color1
                ){
                    DaysOfWeekButton(
                        onClick =
                        {
                            viewModel.snapChanged(day)
                            if(viewModel.rememem[day]) person1.value.set(day, 1)
                            else person1.value.set(day, 0)
                        },
                        day = day
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Text("${person1.value}")
    }
}
```

on screen i have 7 buttons and every time i click on one of them they change color.
how can i solve the problem use VM. States on screen changes, but not saved when switching the screen.

Thank you!

Comment: you don't need to use remember with view models - in this case view model is responsible for storing the data

Comment: @PylypDukhov thank you for answer. i edit my question, pls chek it.

Comment: You're creating a new view model on each recomposition with `viewModel: MyViewModel = MyViewModel()`. use `viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()` instead, this function is gonna cache it for you

Comment: I get this: Expression 'viewModel' of type 'MyViewModel' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67753710/3585796)